# Java logical bit shift error with decimals

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This one works fine:

```
short x = (short)(0xffff >>> 10);
```

i.e. x = 3F (63)

But when the same is done but with decimal representation:

```
short x = (short)((short)(-1) >>> 10);
```

then x is still FFFF (-1).

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `short` `-1` gets promoted to a `int` with value `-1`, which is :

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

After shifting it 10 bits to the right, you have:

```
0000 0000 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

To fix it, you have to take the appropriate part of the int:

```
short x = (short)((-1 & 0xFFFF) >>> 10);
```

This way, the `(-1 & 0xFFFF)`  is already an int, so it doesn't contain the leading `1`'s.

Comment: This is the reason I cast it to short, what doesn't really help. How can it be resolved?

Comment: Well, this one works but makes the code much messy than doing it in c with unsigned primitive types. Is there "cleaner" solution?

Comment: The cleanest solution would be: `short x = 0x3F;`.